# How can I validate step by step using yup and react-hook-form?

Tags: axios, react-hook-form, yup

```
    const schema = yup.object().shape({
      email: yup
        .string()
        .required()
        .email('wrong email.')
        .test('unique email', 'already using', async (value) => {
          try {
            const res = await axios.post('/accounts/emailcheck', { email: value });
            return res.data.possible;
          } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
          }
        }),
  })

    const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm({ mode: 'onBlur', resolver: yupResolver(schema) });
```

i want use axios only (requied, email) are ok.
But it works allways onBlur.

How can I validate step by step using yup and react-hook-form?